# @Valid annotation doesn't force validation unless its called from the rest layer

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation

I am developing a rest service using spring rest, in the rest layer of my code, I annotate the user input with @Valid in order to trigger validation.

```
public ResponseEntity postOrder(@Valid @RequestBody Order order) {

        orderService.postSingleOrder(order);

        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
}
```

This works just fine, but when I try to do the same in some code which is triggered based on `ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>`, the @Valid annotation didn't triggered any validation to work, I had to invoke the validator manually like the following :

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
validator.validate(order);
```

Any idea how to activate the @Valid annotation ?

Comment: For JUnit tests, that would be the simplest way. In your integration tests you should make sure the Spring context is properly initialized and handles that automatically.

Comment: yes, but I have some code which is triggered based on ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>, and I need to enforce validation there as well .. any idea what should be done ?

Comment: That doesn't sound like something testable with unit tests.

Comment: I don't care about any of your code. But there are things you test with unit tests and things you test with integration tests.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling that method from an `ApplicationListener`... You have now tied your application to the web. You should be calling a service layer and validate in that to. To do so use the `@Validated` annotation and register a `MethodValidationPostProcessor` to detect such methods.